# Lubuntu Light Locker settings incorreectly starts power saving mode

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, screensaver, light-locker

In Lubuntu 14.04 64-bit on a desktop computer, my monitor goes to power saving mode almost immediately after the blank screen has appeared, regardless of the Light Locker settings. I do not want the display to be switched off that soon.

With the settings illustrated by the screenshot below, my monitor goes to power saving mode after only a couple of minutes of inactivity. Is the Light Locker buggy or have I misunderstood the settings?

[image]